# c# cannot play wav file

Tags: c#, audio, media-player

Trying to create software which has textbox where user can type word or phrases and program will use google translate to "speak" those words and download that speech to wav or mp3 file and then play that file.

Everything works fine, except playback. File will be loaded to computer but when playing it, Visual Studio gives an error that file is not valid wav file.
When playing file manually from computer, media player plays it fine!

```
 private void Puhu(string Sana) {

WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0;      Windows;)");

 string encstr = string.Empty;

  string filename = "tts.wav"; 

  string s = Sana;

  encstr = Uri.EscapeDataString(s);

  web.DownloadFile("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fi&q=" + encstr, ".\\" + filename);

   (new SoundPlayer(@"tts.wav")).Play(); // this line wont work!! Audio format is wrong!

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of your file that downloaded is `MP3` file. and [`System.Media.SoundPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) only supports `WAV` file:

from MSDN:

> `SoundPlayer` class supports loading a .wav file from a file path, a URL, a Stream that contains a .wav file, or an embedded resource that contains a .wav file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using the Windows Media Player control?

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562851(v=vs.85).aspx

I recall that the SoundPlayer is kind of specific in which format you have to deliver the wave file..